# T turning into what sounds like a trill in Irish English?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics, hiberno-english

I have been recently watching a channel run by an Irish guy and he has many interesting speech quirks (like the fact he still pronounces "wh-" like <hw>). But the thing that puzzles me most is the way he pronounces the word "layout". Three times so far, I've heard him pronounce the T in "layout" basically like a rolled R. For example, listen to the way he says it at 52:57 in [this video](https://youtu.be/Eq3bUFgEcb4?t=3171).
(He does it again a few seconds later)

Have you heard this before? Is it specific to certain regions? How would you call this sound?

Comment: No, there is no r at all, rolled or otherwise.

Comment: You might want to check out this Youtube post. Until I watched it last night, I had no idea why nns often sound klunky pronouncing words like ***trip*** and ***drip***. I now realize that I'm actually virtually *incapable* of enunciating either of those words the way the orthography would suggest. My ***trip*** starts with ***ch** as in **chin***, not ***t** as in **tin***, and my ***drip*** starts with ***g** as in **gin***, not ***d** as in **din***. Same as most native speakers, but unless it had been explicitly pointed out I'd never have realized that!

Comment: [...link for above.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCmTKLhHyPc) Years ago I was fascinated to discover that not only do most people pronounce ***prints*** and ***prince*** exactly the same - they consistently deny this, and keep asking me to hear what they think is an obvious difference (but it's mostly a difference in the speaker's *mind*, not his mouth! :)

Comment: I hear the reduced /t/ at 52.57 as a minimally-articulated /d/, not a "rolled R". Similar to the way many/most Americans reduce /t/ to /d/ in lots of words, rather than the way Liverpudlian Cilla Black, for example, stereotypically reduced ***Lot of love = Lotta love*** to ***Lorra love***. I think most Irish speakers today would rather copy Americans than Liverpudlians!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, what you're hearing there is *flapping*, the pronunciation of /t/ as voiced [ɾ]. This is most commonly associated with American English, but it can be found across dialects. As [Wikipedia notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping), it is quite characteristic of "(especially Northern) Irish English." If [Discogs is to be believed](https://www.discogs.com/artist/5374097-Martin-Keary), that speaker is originally from Limerick, which would make him a speaker of Irish English, though of course not *Northern* Irish English.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting links!